# cant figure out how to acces these elements

Tags: c++, sdl-2

this is my header

```
#include <SDL.h>
class Grid
{

public:
int** Cells;
int x;
int y;
SDL_Color* palette[255];
Grid(int,int,int);
~Grid();
void DrawGrid(SDL_Renderer*);
void SetPalette(int c, int r, int g, int b, int a);
};
```

and this is my source:

```
Grid::Grid(int a,int b,int s)
{
std::cout << "grid constructed";
x = a;
y = b;
Grid::Cells = (int**) malloc(x*s);
for (int i = 0;i < x;i++)
{
    Grid::Cells[i] = (int*)malloc(y*s);
}

    SetPalette(1, 255, 255, 255, 0);
}

void Grid::DrawGrid(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{

        std::cout << Grid::palette[Cells[i][o]].r << " : " << Cells[i][o];
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, palette[Cells[i][o]].r, palette[Cells[i][o]].g, palette[Cells[i][o]].b, palette[Cells[i][o]].a);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, i, o);

}

void Grid::SetPalette(int c, int r, int g, int b, int a)
{
palette[c].r = r;
```

i have this for green blue and alpha too
    }

it says expression must have class type. how do i fix
i have tried hard to figure it out. so i hope i get an answer at least

i did remove some of the irellevant code so it wouldn't take too much space

Comment: palette is an array of pointers, you need to dereference before accessing the members, change any `palette[].` to `palette[]->`.

Comment: Your use of Cells does not match its declaration. `Grid::palette[Cells[i][o]]` implies a 2D array of integers. You have declared only a double pointer to ints viz. `int** Cell;`

Comment: cells is a 2D array and it works. it was when i introduced palette it got confusing

Comment: On a related note: why does `palette` store pointers, and why don't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: i swapped palette[]. for palette-> now the program stops working

Comment: havent gotten to vectors yet. il take a look now

Comment: Also, do use `new` and `delete` in C++ instead of the archaic C allocation functions. It saves you a lot of headaches, not least the accurate calculation of the allocation size (which I'm 99% sure that you've got wrong).

Comment: so how would i fix that? im quite new to c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allocate memory for your palette elements. Without modifying data layout (which is bad, see below), you'll need at least allocate elements in your constructor (prior to `SetPalette`):

```
for(int i = 0; i != 255; i++) {
    palette[i] = new SDL_Color;
}
```

(you will also need to release this memory e.g. in destructor).

With palette declared as `SDL_Color* palette[255];`, expression `palette[c]` have type `SDL_Color*`. Accessing structure field with `.` operator needs structure, not a pointer - so direct solution is `palette[c]->r` (or manually dereferencing and using `.`, but that's exactly what `->` does).

However allocating a lot of so small objects have a relatively high cost and in given example there is no point to do so. If your palette size is constant (as it is) you could just use `SDL_Color palette[255]` and remove all allocation/deallocation code (and there will be no need for `->` since type of `palette[c]` is now `SDL_Color`). If size isn't known at compile time - you can allocate array of colours with a single allocation (`malloc` or `new[]`). And if size is changing during runtime, it is probably easier to use `vector`.

Comment: so i did that but it doesn't work. if you have time, can you pls help me?

Comment: Not if you wouldn't tell what exactly "doesn't work" and what you did.

Comment: found a work around. now i need to speed up the code. i got the vs2015 project [here][code] if you want to take a look. btw, i know the code is crap.

[code]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz-PYBgWOisTeTQzOVNLMk5HR28